# Stackoverflow error when trying to dispatch MouseEvents. mouseMoved works but mouseDragged does not

Tags: java, mousemove, stack-overflow, mousemotionevent

I've been trying to implement mouse motion event dispatches but I continue to get a stack overflow error. It works for the mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) method but not for mouseDragged(MouseEvent e). Does anybody have a clue as to why? Are there any solutions?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {

public Test() { 
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
         public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
             System.err.println("moved outside");
         }
         public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            System.err.println("dragged outside");
         }
    });

    JPanel inside = new JPanel();
    inside.setLocation(0, 0);
    inside.setSize(100, 100);
    inside.setBackground(Color.RED);

    inside.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("dragged inside");

            //The error occurs here when I begin dragging 
            //here and continue dragging to any other location.

            Test.this.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("moved inside");
            Test.this.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
    });
    add(inside);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test client = new Test();
}
}
```

My actual project uses many inside components and my goal is to have each component implement their own mouse press/click/release actions and have the frame handle mouse motions and dragging that influences all of the components.

Here is a similar code that does work for both mouse motion methods.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2 {

public static void main(String... args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            final JComponent outside = new JPanel();
            JComponent inside = new JPanel();
            inside.setBackground(Color.red);
            inside.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            inside.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("dragged inside");
                    outside.dispatchEvent(e);
                }
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("moved inside");
                    outside.dispatchEvent(e);
                }
            });

            outside.add(inside);
            outside.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            outside.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.err.println("moved outside");
                }
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.err.println("dragged outside");
                }
            });

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(outside);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MouseMotionListener` in the `inside` is generating a new event. That event will be caught again by the very same `MouseMotionListener`, creating an endless loop. Since you are creating an event when the previous one is still unfinished, they will stack up until a `StackOverflowError` explodes your application.

Your second code does not have this problem because the `inside` delegates to the `outside` and it finishes there.

Comment: In the first code, why is the very same MouseMotionListener called? Is using Test.this in Test.this.dispatchevent(e); the problem? I'm puzzled as to why it works with mouseMoved. I noticed that when using mouseMoved, the "moved inside" pops up much more than "moved outside" as compared to the second code.

Comment: There are two `MouseMotionListener`s in the first code. The mouse is moved on the `inside` panel. Both listeners will fire, since the mouse is moving on the panel and on the window. The `inside` listener create a new event and post it to Swing, which delivers it to both listeners. The `inside` listener create a new event and post it to Swing, which delivers it to both listeners. The `inside` listener create a new event and post it to Swing, which delivers it to both listeners. The `inside` listener create a new event and post it to Swing, which delivers it to both listeners... BOOM!